# Help with tweet media entities

Tags: php, twitter

I just came across Tweet Entities and I want to add it to my tweets! I have read over and over in the API, but I still can't get it to work. This is what I have:

```
$entities = array(
    "media_url" => $picture_url,
    "url" => $short_url,
    "type" => "photo"
);
$status = $connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $twitterStatus, 'include_entities' => 1, 'entities' => $entities));
```

Part of `print_r($status)` includes:

```
[entities] => stdClass Object ( 
    [user_mentions] => Array ( ) 
    [hashtags] => Array ( ) 
    [urls] => Array ( 
        [0] => stdClass Object ( 
            [url] => http://myf.la/sh/9nlex 
            [indices] => Array ( 
                [0] => 6 
                [1] => 28 
            ) 
            [expanded_url] => 
        ) 
    ) 
) 
[retweet_count] => 0 
[place] => 
[in_reply_to_user_id] => 
[in_reply_to_status_id] =>
```

What else do I have to add in my entities array? You can't add everything the [docs](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_entities) asks you too.

I think it's a known issue since it's a new API. Read [here](http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/browse_thread/thread/99b451ce5d8259ce#).

Comment: Aren't entities recognized automatically by twitter from regular tweets? I always thought that is how they work.

Comment: @zerkms: I am really new to this -- it might do that. But in the links I provided, it looked like you could add media to the tweets?

Comment: @phpnerd211: nope, you just post **regular** tweet and twitter **automatically** extracts media from it

Comment: http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show/82425283357052929.xml?include_entities=1 --- here is a sample of *my* recent tweet. I've just made it with tweetdeck. As you see - media is extracted automatically.

Comment: @Zerkms: How do I get my media in there when POSTING a tweet?

Comment: @phpnerd211: you cannot do that when you're posting, just because you haven't posted yet ;-) But you can retrieve it right after you've done it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to specify your media (entities) manually - twitter will extract it automatically.

http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show/82425283357052929.xml?include_entities=1 --- here is my recent tweet, with entities.

Comment: How exactly does twitter recognize media (in my case photos) for a tweet? Is there anyway I need to format my link in order for this picture to show up under the "Tweet Media" sidebar on the twitter website when looking at the tweet sent via my app?

Comment: @phpnerd211: no, you don't need to do anything special for that. Just post tweets as-is and twitter will do rest of the work. Just have some experiments and see.

Answer (score 0):

Using OAuth method you can do the POST statusesupdate_with_media..

Just download this example and check

I posted about this last week.. [check this and download sample code](http://www.stackcomplete.com/twitter-post-statusesupdate_with_media-example-demo-download/)

Change the config.php key from your Twiiter App

```
<?php
    define('API_KEY', '');/*Your Consumer key*/
    define('API_SEC','');/*Your Consumer secret*/
?>
```

Run index.html file you can see the form to POST the twitter update...